# When running tests in Flask RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I used SQLAlchemy for database management in Flask application, once running integration tests using pytest this error arises: `RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set`.

I set the variable `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/app"` in `.flaskenv` file. I have done manual tests in Postman and everything went well, but once I tried to run the test with pytest the error arose.
Here is the code snippet:

```
import pytest
import json
from backend.app import app


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def load_env_vars():
    import dotenv

    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_path=".flaskenv")


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    app.config["TESTING"] = True
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client


# Test login endpoint
def test_login_user(client):
    payload = {"username": "testuser", "password": "password123"}
    response = client.post("/login", json=payload)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert "token" in response.json
```

Here is the stack trace error after running `pytest tests/`

```
    ========================== test session starts ===========================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-7.4.2, pluggy-1.2.0
rootdir: D:\link_b_flaskapp\backend
plugins: dotenv-0.5.2
collected 0 items / 1 error

================================= ERRORS =================================
_______________ ERROR collecting tests/test_integration.py _______________ 
.venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py:341: in from_call
    result: Optional[TResult] = func()
.venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py:372: in <lambda>
    call = CallInfo.from_call(lambda: list(collector.collect()), "collect").venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:531: in collect
    self._inject_setup_module_fixture()
.venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:545: in _inject_setup_module_fixture
    self.obj, ("setUpModule", "setup_module")
.venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:310: in obj
    self._obj = obj = self._getobj()
.venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:528: in _getobj
    return self._importtestmodule()
.venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:617: in _importtestmodule        
    mod = import_path(self.path, mode=importmode, root=self.config.rootpath)
.venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\pathlib.py:567: in import_path
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
C:\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006: in _gcd_import
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:983: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:967: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:677: in _load_unlocked
    ???
.venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\assertion\rewrite.py:178: in exec_module   
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
tests\test_integration.py:4: in <module>
    from backend.app import app
app.py:5: in <module>
    app = create_app()
__init__.py:93: in create_app
    db.init_app(app)
.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py:311: in init_app     
    "Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set."  
E   RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' must be set.
======================== short test summary info ========================= 
ERROR tests/test_integration.py - RuntimeError: Either 'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI' or 'SQLALCHEMY_BINDS' m...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
============================ 1 error in 1.81s ============================
```

Here is the `__init__.py` of the app

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from datetime import timedelta

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


# local imports
from .config import app_config
from .extensions import jwt, db, bcrypt, migrate
from .models import TokenBlocklist


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get("SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI")
    app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = os.environ.get("JWT_SECRET_KEY")
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = os.environ.get("DATABASE_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS")
    app.config["JWT_ALGORITHM"] = os.environ.get("JWT_ALGORITHM")
    app.config["FLASK_DEBUG"] = os.environ.get("FLASK_DEBUG")


    jwt.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    # Register blueprints and initialize extensions here
    from .routes.user_routes import user_bp
    from .routes.admin_routes import admin_bp
    from .routes.auth_routes import auth_bp

    app.register_blueprint(user_bp, url_prefix="/user")
    app.register_blueprint(auth_bp, url_prefix="/auth")
    app.register_blueprint(admin_bp, url_prefix="/admin")

    return app
```

`.flaskenv` file

```
FLASK_DEBUG = 1
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost/app"
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
# jw configuration
JWT_SECRET_KEY = "secret_key"
JWT_ALGORITHM = "HS256"
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error raised? Maybe include the whole stack trace.

Comment: @danzel I have included the whole stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this import:

```
from backend.app import app
```

Apparently, in `app.py`, you instantiate an app on module level. The error is raised because the import happens before any fixture is executed. I guess `app.py` is only used to actually run the application. If you really need to import `app.py` in other modules, you can take a look at the [`__main__` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html#idiomatic-usage) to learn how to handle this kind of situation.

Luckily, you already implemented the `create_app` factory function. Instead of importing an already initialized app, create it in a fixture like this:

```
import pytest
import json
from backend.app import create_app


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def load_env_vars():
    import dotenv

    dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_path=".flaskenv")

@pytest.fixture
def app(load_env_vars):  # explicit dependency to ensure this is only executed after load_env_vars
    return create_app()

@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    app.config["TESTING"] = True
    with app.test_client() as client:
        yield client


# Test login endpoint
def test_login_user(client):
    payload = {"username": "testuser", "password": "password123"}
    response = client.post("/login", json=payload)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert "token" in response.json
```